# Hangfire with Azure sql database and MSMQ keeps some messages en-queued for good

Tags: azure-sql-database, msmq, hangfire

I am using hangfire 1.6.9 and configured to use sql azure as storage and MSMQ. When some messages are en-queued and processed successfully, there are some which stays in en-queued state for ever.
I observed that by not using MSMQ everything works well. So it seems that something happens after the message is picked up from MSMQ.I enabled trace logs but have not been able to catch anything so far. Any idea would be of great help

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the problem was to do with the service tier we were using for azure sql. The service tier was basic where we have the maximum of 5 [DTUs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-what-is-a-dtu)

We upgraded to standard tier where we can get 50 DTUs at the minimum and everything started to work properly including the overall performance of the application itself